# Nested design in R using aov and lmer

Tags: r, nested, anova, lme4

I am trying to figure out the correct R code for this problem.

There are 10 golfers from the US and 10 golfers from the UK. Each player plays 5 rounds of golf in the UK and 5 rounds in the US. There are three specific questions:

1. Do golfers from the UK or US have higher scores? (is there an effect of nationality)
2. Do scores differ when playing in the US or UK course? (is there an effect of course.location)
3. Do golfers have a 'home field advantage', where the effect of playing in the US or UK depends on if the golfer comes from the US or the UK (ie, is there an interaction between nationality and course.location)?

The data are coded with the variable 'golfer' taking values 1-20, as opposed to values 1-10 within each nationality.

First off, is this a nested design? That is, am I correct in saying that golfer is nested within nationality? If so, is this the correct anova formula:

```
aov(score ~ nationality + course.location + nationality*course.location + Error(nationality/golfer)
```

What confuses me a bit is that if I were to do this using a mixed model framework, this formula makes the most sense to me:

```
lmer(score ~ nationality + course.location + nationality*course.location + (1|course.location:golfer))
```

Here, the random effect of golfer depends on whether that golfer is playing in the US or the UK.

So are these analogous? Is one wrong? Are both wrong? In the lmer framework I don't see a need to use the nesting formulation, but in the anova framework I feel like I am missing the fact that the random effect of golfer depends on course location.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

(as a bonus question, what exactly is the difference between the random effect term (1+course.location|golfer) and (1|course.location:golfer) when course. location is binary?)

Comment: The MLM framework assumes that both L1 and L2 units are a random sample from a population of possible L1 / L2 units. Here, you have specific players; and, more importantly, two specific countries. (a) they don't represent a random sample and (b) I don't think you care about generalizing to the country effect in general. So, you're not controlling for random variation--you're controlling for two specific countries

Comment: I also don't think this is a nested design. Golfer nationality is an attribute of the golfers. You don't appear to be trying to estimate an EB 'grand mean' for US and UK golfers.

Comment: `(1+ course.location|golfer)` specifies a random intercept for `golfer`s and a random intercept for `course.location`. `(1|course.location:golfer)` specifies a random intercept for the interaction of the two terms